# GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync: "An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set."

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, asp.net-core-webapi, identityserver4

I have checked most of the questions on SO, but didn't find my answer.

I'm trying to get a JWT token from a Identity server.

Here's how:

```
  var discoveryDocument = new DiscoveryDocumentRequest
            {
                Address = "https://admin.blabla.app:5000/",
                Policy =
                {
                    RequireHttps = false
                }
            };

  var auth = httpClient.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(discoveryDocument).Result;
```

The error I'm getting is `An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.`

**DiscoveryDocumentRequest**

```
{
    "Policy": {
        "LoopbackAddresses": [
            "localhost",
            "127.0.0.1"
        ],
        "Authority": "https://admin.blabla.app:5000",
        "AuthorityValidationStrategy": {},
        "RequireHttps": false,
        "AllowHttpOnLoopback": true,
        "ValidateIssuerName": true,
        "ValidateEndpoints": true,
        "EndpointValidationExcludeList": [],
        "AdditionalEndpointBaseAddresses": [],
        "RequireKeySet": true
    },
    "Address": "https://admin.blabla.app:5000/",
    "ClientId": null,
    "ClientSecret": null,
    "ClientAssertion": {
        "Type": null,
        "Value": null
    },
    "ClientCredentialStyle": 1,
    "AuthorizationHeaderStyle": 0,
    "Parameters": [],
    "Version": {
        "Major": 1,
        "Minor": 1,
        "Build": -1,
        "Revision": -1,
        "MajorRevision": -1,
        "MinorRevision": -1
    },
    "Content": null,
    "Method": {
        "Method": "GET"
    },
    "RequestUri": null,
    "Headers": [
        {
            "Key": "Accept",
            "Value": [
                "application/json"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "Properties": {}
}
```

This code is on a windows service.

Fun fact: Same code works on different windows machines. Why? What might be the problem?

Comment: Hi @Gerald, checking HttpClient's [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/44655fd0dc7b08cd20eced97981bcad99e48ef67/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs#L749) shows that the mentioned error is thrown if the provided uri is null and the httpclient's BaseAddress property is null, or if the provided uri is a relative uri and the BaseAdress property is null. So I think that somewhere in your code (or IdentityModel's code) HttpClient is receiving a null uri or a relative uri while the BaseAdress property is null.

Comment: Can you please share the full stacktrace of the error. It will probably be useful in pinpointing the origin of the problem and determining if it's an issue with your code or IdentityModel's code.

Comment: Hi @Gerald Hughes,From the error message, it seems the request url is not correct. I think you could firstly use fiddler to check the request url.

Comment: As per the DiscoveryDocumentRequest that you have shared, the 'RequestUri' is null. Not sure if the 'BaseAddress' field for the httpClient has a value when you invoke it. If httpClient.BaseAddress doesn't have a value either, then the error is bound to be thrown since both 'RequestUri' and BaseAddress are going to be found as null during evaluation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to this [sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/main/samples/Quickstarts/1_ClientCredentials/src/Client/Program.cs) and please write:

```
 var client = new HttpClient();

            var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("https://admin.blabla.app:5000/");
            if (disco.IsError)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(disco.Error);
                return;
            }
```

please check your URL https://admin.blabla.app:5000/ your error is related to your URL you can test your code by https://demo.identityserver.io/